# How can I change other element's style on hover in scss

Tags: css, sass

I am using scss.
On situation like this, how can I change target element's style on hover child element?
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-haibt-60yph

```
.parent {
  // some styles..
  
  .child {
    // some styles..
  }
}

.target {
  // some styles..
}
```

I tried using @at-root inside the child, but couldn't figure out. (code below)

```
  .target {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
  .parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;

    .child {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
  
      &:hover {
        @at-root .target {
          background-color: green;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Kindly help..

Answer (score 1):

the message given is clear, @root cannot be used that way.

but you can trick css via pointer-events:

```
  body {
  .parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    pointer-events:none;

    .child {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
      pointer-events:auto;
    }
  
    &:hover {         
        background-color: green;            
      }
    
  }

  .target {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

or did you mean

```
body {
  .parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    pointer-events:none;

    .child {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
      pointer-events:auto;
    }
  
    &:hover ~ .target {         
        background-color: green;
        
      }
    
  }

  .target {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: second code you gave is what I wanted, but I need my parent to have cursor: pointer. so I can not use pointer-events: none on parent. This trick is very useful though thanks for sharing

Comment: @Peppermintc , in that case, then JavaScript is your friend. CSS do not have a parent selector, even using sass or else compiler, it only produces CSS.